# Install IoT Ubuntu without SSO

Tags: ubuntu-core

I was looking for a way to install Ubuntu on a raspberry pi without an SSO account as one of my main reasons for moving to Ubuntu is privacy and no accounts. Searched around with no luck then asked on the Ubuntu site with this response: 
"Yes you can install without…, however this site is for the co-ordination of the Ubuntu project(s), and not support."

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure whats ambiguous about it? I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Raspberry pi 3 without a SSO Account. As per the tutorial on https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3 step 1 says you need to register an account and if you move on with the installation to step 5 without doing step 1, you cant continue.

Comment: Search how to install Ubuntu on a raspberry pi, you'll find how-to's for installing regular Ubuntu or a Ubuntu flavor. Ubuntu-core requires a sso account and may not be what you wanted anyway..